# Running Spark program on Azure HDInsight using local drive

Tags: azure, apache-spark, benchmarking, azure-hdinsight

I have a program I want to run and benchmark on Azure. We've already tested this program on Amazon EC2 and want to try and mirror the hardware as closely as possible. On EC2 the data we're accessing was put on an SSD. We have the data in a blob on Azure.

When we make an HDInsight cluster, do we simply copy the data from the blob to the cluster and it will be on an SSD (provided our cluster is requisitioned with an SSD?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You would use

```
hadoop distcp <wasb://src-url> <hdfs://dest-url>
```

from the hadoop command line, moving the data from blob storage to local HDFS.

FYI-The suggested architecture is to use Blob storage/Data Lake and not HDFS.

**References:**
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/

Comment: Is using the Blob as fast as the SSD. We're not interested in best practices at the moment, but rather bench-marking against our EC2 data.

Comment: I haven't bench marked them, but I would think local disk may be faster. Should be easy to bench mark against both once you have it in HDFS

Comment: The destination address for local HDFS on HDInsight cluster is hdfs://mycluster/

Comment: Also make sure you use VM type for worker nodes with SSDs, like D14v2